# Issues with having two carousels on the same page with custom jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, carousel

I have some jQuery that works great when one carousel is on the page. I need to have two carousels in the same page and it's currently not working. Can someone please tell me how to make it work?

```
var Carousel = (function($) {   
    var $carousel = $('.carousel');
    var activeItemIndex = 0;
    var s;

    return {
        settings: {
            delay: 10000,
            items: $carousel.find('.carousel__item'),
            totalItems: 0,
            dots: $carousel.find('.carousel__dots'),
            dotLinks: $carousel.find('.carousel__dot-link'),
            timeout: 0,
        },

        init: function(args) {
            if ($carousel.length) {
                s = $.extend({}, this.settings, args);
                s.totalItems = s.items.length;

                if (s.totalItems > 1) {
                    this.setupDotsData();
                    this.activate();
                    this.eventListeners();
                    $carousel.addClass('active');
                }
            }
        },

        eventListeners: function() {
            s.dotLinks.on('click', function() {
                var index = $(this).data('index');
                Carousel.stop();
                Carousel.show(index);
            });
        },

        setupDotsData: function() {
            s.dots.each(function() {
                $(this).find('li').each(function(index) {
                    $(this).data('index', index);
                });
            });
        },

        activate: function() {
            if (s.totalItems > 1) {
                Carousel.show(0);
            } else {
                s.items.eq(0).addClass('active');
            }
        },

        show: function(index) {
            s.items.removeClass('active');
            s.dotLinks.removeClass('active');
            s.items.eq(index).addClass('active');
            s.dotLinks.filter(':nth-child(' + (index + 1) + ')').addClass('active');
            activeItemIndex = index;

            Carousel.play();
        },

        next: function(e) {
            var nextItemIndex = activeItemIndex + 1 >= s.totalItems ? 0 : activeItemIndex + 1;
            e && e.preventDefault();
            Carousel.stop();
            Carousel.show(nextItemIndex);
        },

        play: function() {
            s.timeout = window.setTimeout(Carousel.next, s.delay);
        },

        stop: function() {
            window.clearTimeout(s.timeout);
        }
    };
})(jQuery);

Carousel.init();
```

[Example on JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/thebluehorse/dmz7wk6f/)

Comment: I'm about to leave, so I can't look into the code very deeply. However... I noticed you're using $(".carousel") for the whole plugin. Consider using something like $(".carousel").each(...), and then referencing elements in that particular .carousel instance as this.find(".selector_here").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need some modifications for handling multiple instance of `Carousel`:

https://jsfiddle.net/dmz7wk6f/7/

Comment: Thanks so much. Just curious -- but could you explain what exactly `$.proxy()` is doing and how it works that's towards the end of the script?

Comment: @Cofey, it helps passing context object `this` so that when `next` is executed after `delay`, the context of that function is the single `carousel` instance instead of `window` object.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (loop through each carousel, grab the id and initialize it):

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/4o00o7n6/

```
$(".carousel").each(function(x){

    var carouselId = $(this).attr('id');
    var Carousel = (function($) {
        'use strict';
        //var wrap = $('.carousel');
        var wrap = $('#' + carouselId);
        var activeItemIndex = 0;
        var s;

        return {
            settings: {
                delay: 10000,
                items: wrap.find('.carousel__item'),
                totalItems: 0,
                dots: wrap.find('.carousel__dots'),
                dotLinks: wrap.find('.carousel__dot-link'),
                timeout: 0,
            },

            init: function(args) {
                if (wrap && wrap.length) {
                    s = $.extend({}, this.settings, args);
                    s.totalItems = s.items.length;

                    if (s.totalItems > 1) {
                        this.setupDotsData();
                        this.activate();
                        this.eventListeners();
                        wrap.addClass('active');
                    }
                }
            },

            eventListeners: function() {
                s.dotLinks.on('click', function() {
                    var index = $(this).data('index');
                    Carousel.stop();
                    Carousel.show(index);
                });
            },

            setupDotsData: function() {
                s.dots.each(function() {
                    $(this).find('li').each(function(index) {
                        $(this).data('index', index);
                    });
                });
            },

            activate: function() {
                if (s.totalItems > 1) {
                    Carousel.show(0);
                } else {
                    s.items.eq(0).addClass('active');
                }
            },

            show: function(index) {
                s.items.removeClass('active');
                s.dotLinks.removeClass('active');
                s.items.eq(index).addClass('active');
                s.dotLinks.filter(':nth-child(' + (index + 1) + ')').addClass('active');
                activeItemIndex = index;

                Carousel.play();
            },

            next: function(e) {
                var nextItemIndex = activeItemIndex + 1 >= s.totalItems ? 0 : activeItemIndex + 1;
                e && e.preventDefault();
                Carousel.stop();
                Carousel.show(nextItemIndex);
            },

            play: function() {
                s.timeout = window.setTimeout(Carousel.next, s.delay);
            },

            stop: function() {
                window.clearTimeout(s.timeout);
            }
        };
    })(jQuery);

    Carousel.init();

});
```